# How can I get dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold to use the secrets.json connection string?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I have a connection string in the secrets.json. I don't want to check the password into the repository.

This works:

`dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=MyServerName;Database=MyDBName;User Id=sa;Password=abc123;"`

I added a user secret:

> dotnet user-secrets list
>
> ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString = Provider=....;

However all attempts to get it to use this instead of typing it manually have failed.

I have tried:

`dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold name=MyConnectionString` which gives this error:

> A named connection string was used, but the name 'ConnectionStrings.MyConnectionString' was not found in the application's configuration. Note that named connection strings are only supported when using 'IConfiguration' and a service provider, such as in a typical ASP.NET Core application. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=850912 for more information.

Is it not possible to do this? I cannot find any documentation, and other SO questions asking this seem to have gone unanswered.

Comment: Have you configured your app to read from user secrets?

Comment: I think you have to do that by scaffolding, as it says `#warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. You can avoid scaffolding the connection string by using the Name= syntax to read it from configuration`. So presumably I would scaffold using Name= and it would then build the context with the code to read it from the secrets json. I could manually edit it to read from the secrets but I want to scaffold with it so that I can make a batch file and check it into the solution to rebuild the model